# Require Windows credentials on WPF app start

Tags: c#, wpf, security, active-directory

I have a WPF application that will work offline with local data. On app start I need the user to re-enter their Windows credentials to verify that they are in fact the correct Windows user.

Is there a .NET method to make the user re-login when the app starts?

Or do I need to create a login page and logic and compare against the current user [like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/wpf-login-verification-using-active-directory)?

Comment: If my computer is unlocked and I walk away, I don't want you to be able to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a technology solution to a behavior problem, but, you want to look at the `CredUIPromptForCredentials` API and the `LogonUser` API to prompt and create the token.